# XMLhttprequest.send gives blank array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
> xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
       var jsondata = xmlhttp.responseText;
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("jsondata").value = jsondata;


        console.log(innerHTML = jsondata.word);
        document.getElementById("approved").innerHTML = "Thank you! We will get back to you.";
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", url,false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
xmlhttp.send("a="+a+ "&b="+b);
```

}

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');
    }
    exit;
}


$req = file_get_contents("php://input");
$req = json_decode($req);
```

Comment: NOTE: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` are **NOT** request headers and only make things more difficult for you if you put those headers in a cross origin request... they are **response** headers that tell the browser the server is allowing it to access the servers resource - is `url` same origin?

Comment: Secondly, you shouldn't use `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` when you make a (deprecated) synchronous request (i.e. third parameter to open is `false`) - see [warning in documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)

Comment: Thirdly, your PHP does `$req = json_decode($req);`  ... but you are not sending JSON

Comment: Fourthly, the PHP never prints anything.

Comment: Fifthly, if the PHP returns JSON, you need to call `JSON.parse(jsondata)`

Comment: You should be accessing `$_POST['a']` and `$_POST['b']`, not using `php://input`

Comment: Also, `var jsondata = xmlhttp.responseText;` means `jsondata` will be a string, so, `jsondata.word` will be `undefined`

Comment: @JaromandaX No, URL is not the same origin.

Comment: well, save yourself some misery by not adding all those `access-control-` headers in the request, then you can remove them from the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response :p

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are sending CORS **response headers** in a request - this isn't necessary, doesn't do anything, except guarantee a preflight because of non-standard headers - so, remove:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
```

Secondly, you are using `onreadystatechange` in combination with a synchronous (which is deprecated) request - in the code below, made the request asynchronous, and use the more modern `onload`

Hopefully some of the comments will illuminate you on the rest of the changes

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); // we get JSON, so parse it to an Object
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("jsondata").value = data;
        //console.log(innerHTML = jsondata.word); what is this supposed to do? removed because it looks wrong
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true); // use ASYNCHRONOUS request, because it's the 21st century
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send("a="+a+ "&b="+b);
```

and the PHP

```
<?php
// you'll find that the request probably won't be pre-flighted now! But, lets keep this code in just in case
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type');
    }
    exit;
}
// moved this after the conditional exit, no need to send it twice for an OPTIONS request
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'); // not really required, but let's be nice
$a = $_POST["a"];
$b = $_POST["b"];
// send back json, since you client code seems to want "jsondata"
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$a + $b));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `XMLhttprequest.send` is not sending blank request. it is infact sending vaules of a & b. I tried your codes by settgin some random values to  and and be and the `$req` variable is infact being populated with vales of a and b.

```js
<script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'http://localhost/test/test.php';
    var a= 5;
    var b=6;
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var jsondata = xmlhttp.responseText;
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("jsondata").value = jsondata;


            console.log(innerHTML = jsondata.word);
            document.getElementById("approved").innerHTML = "Thank you! We will get back to you.";
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url,false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    xmlhttp.send("a="+a+ "&b="+b);

</script>
```

When I ran this, I got `a=5&b=6`. One problem I see in your code is that you are not echoing the results.
do this:

```
$req = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $req;
```

As per Jaromanda X's suggest, I would like to point out that you are not sending the JSON data to the PHP script, so trying to decode it would give errors.

Comment: you may want to point out that the data sent in the request is NOT JSON ... also, don't duplicate his mistake of setting CORS response headers in the request :p